# Disable automatic sorting on the first column when using jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and I would like to know if there's possible to disable automatic sorting on the first column of the table?

My code looks like this:

```
        /* Default class modification */
        $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
            "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
        } );

        /* API method to get paging information */
        $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
        {
            return {
                "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
                "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
                "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
                "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
                "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
                "iPage":          Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
                "iTotalPages":    Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
            };
        }

        /* Bootstrap style pagination control */
        $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
            "bootstrap": {
                "fnInit": function( oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw ) {
                    var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
                    var fnClickHandler = function ( e ) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if ( oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action) ) {
                            fnDraw( oSettings );
                        }
                    };

                    $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append(
                        '<ul>'+
                            '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">&larr; '+oLang.sPrevious+'</a></li>'+
                            '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">'+oLang.sNext+' &rarr; </a></li>'+
                        '</ul>'
                    );
                    var els = $('a', nPaging);
                    $(els[0]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "previous" }, fnClickHandler );
                    $(els[1]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "next" }, fnClickHandler );
                },

                "fnUpdate": function ( oSettings, fnDraw ) {
                    var iListLength = 5;
                    var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
                    var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
                    var i, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf=Math.floor(iListLength/2);

                    if ( oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                        iStart = 1;
                        iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                    }
                    else if ( oPaging.iPage <= iHalf ) {
                        iStart = 1;
                        iEnd = iListLength;
                    } else if ( oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages-iHalf) ) {
                        iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                        iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                    } else {
                        iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                        iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
                    }

                    for ( i=0, iLen=an.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) {
                        // Remove the middle elements
                        $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();

                        // Add the new list items and their event handlers
                        for ( j=iStart ; j<=iEnd ; j++ ) {
                            sClass = (j==oPaging.iPage+1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                            $('<li '+sClass+'><a href="#">'+j+'</a></li>')
                                .insertBefore( $('li:last', an[i])[0] )
                                .bind('click', function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)-1) * oPaging.iLength;
                                    fnDraw( oSettings );
                                } );
                        }

                        // Add / remove disabled classes from the static elements
                        if ( oPaging.iPage === 0 ) {
                            $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                        } else {
                            $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                        }

                        if ( oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages-1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0 ) {
                            $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                        } else {
                            $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        /* Show/hide table column */
        function dtShowHideCol( iCol ) {
            var oTable = $('#example-2').dataTable();
            var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
            oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
        };

        /* Table #example */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datatable').dataTable( {
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",                    
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { 
                        "bSortable": false, 
                        "aTargets": [ -1 ] // <-- gets last column and turns off sorting
                    } 
                ]
            });
            $('.datatable-controls').on('click','li input',function(){
                dtShowHideCol( $(this).val() );
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Set the [`aaSorting`](http://datatables.net/ref#aaSorting) option to an empty array. It will disable initial sorting, whilst still allowing manual sorting when you click on a column.

```
"aaSorting": []
```

> The aaSorting array should contain an array for each column to be
>   sorted *initially* containing the column's index and a direction string
>   ('asc' or 'desc').

Comment: For the newer version of DataTables (version 1.10.7), see my answer below.

Answer (score 81):

In the newer version of datatables (version 1.10.7) it seems things have changed. The way to prevent DataTables from automatically sorting by the first column is to set the `order` option to an empty array.

You just need to add the following parameter to the DataTables options:

```
"order": []
```

Set up your DataTable as follows in order to override the default setting:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": [],
    // Your other options here...
} );
```

That will override the default setting of `"order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]]`.

You can find more details regarding the `order` option [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order).

Comment: I'd like to clarify that the thing that has changed with newer versions of DataTables is the naming convention of the options has been simplified, but the options themselves haven't changed. The old option names still work; "aaSorting" and "order" are interchangeable.  Also, "aaData" is now "data", "sTitle" is now "title", "bSortable" is now "sortable" and so on.

Comment: When looking for options to configure a Datatable, is better consulting the official documentation, because in most forums usually people don't specify the versions, which cause a lot of confusion when trying to implement in the projects. For DataTables v1.9 and earlier see: [http://legacy.datatables.net/usage](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/). For DataTables 1.10 see: [https://datatables.net/reference/option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/).

Comment: when trying this in `1.10` it is disabling the ability to sort on all columns. i had to use the accepted answer

Answer (score 9):

```
var table;

$(document).ready(function() {

    //datatables
    table = $('#userTable').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.
         "aaSorting": [],
        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url().'admin/ajax_list';?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ ], //first column / numbering column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

    });

});
```

set

```
"targets": [0]
```

to

```
 "targets": [ ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
this.dtOptions = {
    order: [],
    columnDefs: [ {
        'targets': [0], /* column index [0,1,2,3]*/
        'orderable': false, /* true or false */
    }],
    ........ rest all stuff .....
}
```

The above worked fine for me.

(I am using Angular version 7, angular-datatables version 6.0.0 and bootstrap version 4)

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple code for DataTables custom sorting. Its 100% work

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]] // "0" means First column and "desc" is order type; 
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

See in Datatables website

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Answer (score 2):

Add

```js
"aaSorting": []
```

And check if default value is not `null` only set sortable column then

```js
if ($('#table').DataTable().order().length == 1) {
    d.SortColumn = $('#table').DataTable().order()[0][0];
    d.SortOrder = $('#table').DataTable().order()[0][1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of other solution doesn't fix it, try to override the styles to hide the sort togglers:

```
.sorting_asc:after, .sorting_desc:after {
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Datatables for beginners can be so hard while using on server side. You can implement the datatables on server-side with almost no hustle, You should consider using the [DataTables Quick](https://github.com/mohiwalla/cdn.js). I found these to ease my day to day work, which I think every programmer out here will want. **Note:** Don't use it on the production as it may harm your data in some way.